# How can the application only support "LandscapeLeft" oritation in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wrote a application. I need it to support only `LandscapeLeft` orientation. My xaml looks like this:

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape" 
Orientation="LandscapeLeft"
```

However, when I turn the phone to `LandscapeRight`, the page turns automatically. I have overridden the `OnOrientationChanged` function, but it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Did you set e.Handled to true in OnOrientationChanged?

Comment: Does e has a member names Handled?

Answer (score 3):

It's not recommended support only landscape left, but if you want this, your override method should be similar to this:

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
        {
            base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
        }
    }
```